# Python request with Base64 pfx certificate

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, request, base64, pfx

I have an issue with a Base 64 coded pfx File.

First of all i pasted the content of the file into an Editor and saved it as .p12.
I am using the requests_pkcs12 library and getting an OpenSSL.crypto.Error

```
12_filename = 'C:\\Users\\WaleedSaleem\\Desktop\\Zertifikat\\certi_13522.p12'
response = post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False, pkcs12_filename=pkcs12_filename,pkcs12_password=pkcs12_password)
```

Everything else is working fine, only difficulty with the certificate
This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WaleedSaleem/PycharmProjects/U2Care_Python/BFS_API_Test3.py", line 21, in <module>
    response = post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=True, pkcs12_filename=pkcs12_filename,pkcs12_password=pkcs12_password)
  File "C:\Users\WaleedSaleem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_pkcs12.py", line 148, in post
    return request('post', *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WaleedSaleem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_pkcs12.py", line 121, in request
    pkcs12_adapter = Pkcs12Adapter(
  File "C:\Users\WaleedSaleem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_pkcs12.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.ssl_context = create_pyopenssl_sslcontext(pkcs12_data, pkcs12_password_bytes)
  File "C:\Users\WaleedSaleem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_pkcs12.py", line 40, in create_pyopenssl_sslcontext
    p12 = load_pkcs12(pkcs12_data, pkcs12_password_bytes)
  File "C:\Users\WaleedSaleem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 2987, in load_pkcs12
    _raise_current_error()
  File "C:\Users\WaleedSaleem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_get_object', 'header too long')]
```

The pfx File is working totally fine in Postman.
Any idea?

Thx for your help

Comment: i just generated a p12 certificat through Firefox. Added a my pfx and then downloaded it as .p12. Still not working. Getting an 400 as response, the site is not accepting the token.